# How Umbraco GetDictionaryItem works

Tags: umbraco

I am using Visual Studio 2015 in debug mode, and running Diagnostic tool. The Umbraco version is 7.5.3

**My question is:**

Do umbraco always travel back to database everytime it use GetDictionaryItem?

As you can see in my screenshot, everytime I debug, an event was showing it was querying at database, please somebody enlighten me. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*umbraco.library* is getting obsolete - don't use it.

To get dictionary value, just use ***Umbraco.Field("#aliasOfField")***. You can test it using graphic UI in templates section. Second icon from left side is the one responsible for dictionary items. It's retrieved from XML cache, so there is no need to ping database for getting any value to present on the site.

[image]

**Database Caching**

`Umbraco.Field()` uses the Published Content xml cache loaded into memory (from ~/App_Data/Umbraco.config), but `Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue()` will hit the database if the key doesn't exist in the in-memory cache already.  Once it's retrieved the value the first time around though, it should use the cache for subsequent calls as long as the app isn't restarted.

Comment: You can also use `Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("aliasOfField")` if you want to actually get the value and work with it in code before rendering it. I'm actually curious how the caching works for both `Umbraco.Field()` and `Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue()`. I was under the impression that those also hit the database. Is this true? If not, how are the values cached?

Comment: Umbraco.Field() uses the Published Content cache loaded into memory (from ~/App_Data/Umbraco.config), but Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue() will hit the database _if_ the key doesn't exist in the in-memory cache already.

Comment: @RobertFoster edit my answer and we will have perfect response ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @RobertFoster :)